# Can't access cn=config through Apache Directory Studio GUI

Tags: openldap

I am quite familiar with `openldap`. The dynamic configuration is quite new to me. So I wanted to make life easier and change `openldap` configuration through Apache Directory Studio GUI.

`Openldap` is installed on Debian Jessie and Version slapd 2.4.40+dfsg-1+deb8u1 amd64

Tried to follow this way:
http://gos.si/blog/installing-openldap-on-debian-squeeze-with-olc

But I can't access it:

```
ldapsearch -b cn=config -D cn=admin,dc=domain -W
result: 32 No such object
```

First I thought it has to do with the ACLs and removed everything, but no change.

`ldapsearch -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -b cn=config` works

So why does the olcRootDN have no rights? Also in the GUI I don't see the cn=config.
Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I answer it by myself, got it now, big confusion and misunderstanding of the dynamic configuration. Maybe someone has the same problem:

There is a difference between `olcRootDN` in `dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config and dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config`

in my case the `olcRootDN` in `olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config` was not set at all. So I added it like explained in the link and also `olcRootPW`.

Now I can access the `cn=config` in Apache Directory Studio GUI and edit it comfortable. It is good to have two different Passwords to not accidently delete something in `cn=config`

Comment: What did you do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

@Adambean asks how OP did it.

One way to do it is to create an ldif (e.g. config.ldif) file containing:

```
# uncomment this part, if there is no olcRootDN present
# use replace instead of add, if you want to change the root dn
#dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
#changetype: modify
#add: olcRootDN
#olcRootDN: cn=admin,cn=config

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config changetype: modify add: olcRootPW 
olcRootPW: <secret>
```

You can generate a secret using:

```
sudo slappasswd
```

Then simply copy/paste the `{SHAA}blahblahhashvaluegoeshereblah` into the `olcRootPW: <field>` of your ldif file.

And modify it with ldapmodify

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:// -f config.ldif
```

That should do it.

Comment: Got (for first modification) `ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)` and `wrong attributeType at line 4, entry "olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config"` for second entry.